# error running glmnet on 2 combined DTMs (via cBind) in text2vec

Tags: r, text2vec

I created a tf-idf DTM and a n-gram based DTM in text2vec, using the same dataset. now, i am able to run glmnet on each of them separately, but when i combine these 2 DTMs to via cBind, glmnet gives me an error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) :invalid class “dgCMatrix” object: length(Dimnames[1]) differs from Dim[1] which is 43895
```

dtm_train_tfidf = (19579 * 27511) matrix, and

dtm_train_ngram = (19579 * 16384) matrix.

which means that they have the same exact number of rows, and i can combine them using cBind (cbind for matrices) and get a large matrix on which i should be able to run glmnet.
only i am not able to run it and i get this error.
how do i rectify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the bug https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/issues/205. You can use development version from GitHub or just drop colnames of the dtm from hash vectorizer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Dmitriy! you have made an excellent package for us R users. how do i go about using the development version from github or dropping the colnames of the dtm from the hash vectorizer?

Comment: i solved it by running "devtools::install_github("dselivanov/text2vec")". now the code runs perfectly. Thanks Dmitriy!!